# Can't connect QML combobox signal to C++ slot

Tags: c++, qt, combobox

I'm trying to connect currentIndexChanged signal of QML combobox to the slot of my class. 
The problem is, rootObject->findChild always returns NULL, as if that particular combobox didn't exist.

I'm getting these errors:

```
qrc:main.qml:134: ReferenceError: combo is not defined
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::currentIndexChanged(int) to ComboBoxSignalReceiver::cppSlot(int)
```

, although I defined objectName for the combobox.

---

main.cpp

```
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QListView>
#include <QtQuick>
#include <QComboBox>
#include <comboboxsignalreceiver.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


    QStringList event_types;
    event_types.append("concerts");
    event_types.append("exhibitions");

    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQuickView view;
    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:main.qml"));
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);

    QQmlContext *context = view.rootContext();
    QObject* rootObject = view.rootObject();

    context->setContextProperty("comboBoxModel", QVariant::fromValue(event_types));

    QComboBox* combo = rootObject->findChild<QComboBox*>("combo");
    ComboBoxSignalReceiver comboBoxSignalReceiver;

    QObject::connect(combo, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)),
            &comboBoxSignalReceiver, SLOT(cppSlot(int)));

    view.show();

    return app.exec();

}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 510
    height: 400
    clip: true

ComboBox {
        id: comboBox1
        objectName: combo
        model: comboBoxModel
        currentIndex: 0
        x: 418
        y: 8
        width: 84
        height: 20
        activeFocusOnPress: true
    }
}
```

comboboxsignalreceiver.h

```
#include <QObject>
#include <iostream>

class ComboBoxSignalReceiver : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void cppSlot(const int &v) {
       std::cout << "Called the C++ slot with value:" << v;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cast ComboBox to QComboBox, since it instantiates QQuickItem and not QComboBox.
The findChild method works by finding child by objectName which needs to be a **string**. So **combo** should be a string as "combo". 
Further there's no currentIndexChanged signal(atleast i didn't see) for ComboBox element you can use **activated** signal as follows:

```
QQuickItem *item = view.rootObject()->findChild<QQuickItem*>("combo");
if(item) {
    QObject::connect(item,SIGNAL(activated(int)),&comboBoxSignalReceiver,SLOT(cppSlot(int)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `objectName` should be a string. In your case. QML is searching for an object with the identifier `combo`, and did not find one (hence the error message)

```
 objectName: "combo"
```

Should solve your issue.

See [QObject::objectName](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#objectName-prop) property for reference